# C# Dynamically cast object for property grid

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a parent class called Widget. I have a list of Widgets that I store. In this list I store children of Widget like Button, Label, DropDown, etc. When a child is selected in my editor I assign that object (finding it by name in the list of Widgets) to the PropertyGrid. However, because they are stored as type Widget the PropertyGrd only shows the Widget properties. **I want to cast the child Widget to it's actual type when I set it to the PropertyGrid so the PropertyGrid can see the child's properties, but I want to do this dynamically instead of using if/case statements because child widgets use a Plugin system so I won't know what the type is at design time.** I know I have to use reflection and I'm fine with that but I just don't know how to do this.

Since I store my child widgets in a container of parent Widget the child would be stored as Widget wouldn't it? Meaning the PropertyGrid is only seeing Widget properties?

```
Dictionary<string, Widget> Widgets;

Widgets.Add("button1", new Button());  // gets converted to parent Widget

PropGrid.SelectedObject = Widgets["button1"];


public class Button : Widget.Widget
{
    public String Test { get; set; } // this doesn't show up in the property grid
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: Can you show an example property that isn't displaying? If your code is like that shown in Tim's answer, it should already work - so an example would help. Also: is this winforms? Wpf? Or...?

Comment: @MarcGravell `PropertyGrid` is a winforms class. I've added that tag.

Comment: @Tim there are also wpf implementations, iirc (3rd party) - I *assumed* winforms, but wanted to be sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you have some code like this:

```
myPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = widget;
```

Since the [`SelectedObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.selectedobject.aspx) property is of type `object`, it doesn't matter whether you assign it an object that is statically known as an `object`, `Widget`, or `Button`: it will be taken in as an `object`. Your child properties are not appearing for some other reason.

Comment: But I'm storing my objects like Dictionary<string, Widget> Widgets; So when I add a button for example it's stored as a Widget because I do: Widgets.Add("button1", new Button()); So it's being cast to Widget when it's stored in the container which means when I pull it back out it's still of type Widget isn't it? This is how it works in C++ anyway so I assume it's the same for C#.

Comment: @user441521 When you pull it out without casting, its statically-known type (the type the compiler knows about, which you can see in things like when you hover over `widget`) is `Widget`, but its runtime type (which you can see with `widget.GetType()`, among other things) will actually be `Button`. From your description, it sounds like C++ is different in this regard: there's no casting container at runtime that says "this is a Button, but I'm using it as a Widget".

Comment: Just to be 100% clear: in .net, you are assigning it as type `object`; it will use GetType and TypeDescriptor etc to understand the object at runtime.

Comment: You are correct. I forgot to build the button dll which puts it in the plugin folder when loaded dynamically. I see the properties now. Sorry.